# How to open a bootstrap modal window from other component in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal window that needs to open up on a button click, which is working fine. Now, I want to open that same modal window from a different component, I tried something but it isn't working, following is my code,

```
<section>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal()">Sign In</button>
    
    <div id="signInModal" class="modal fade m-5" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="dialog-sizes-name2" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6 class="circularBold signUpHeading">Sign In</h6>
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form [formGroup]="signInForm">    
                            <div class="mt-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn buttons nextBtn circularBold w-100" (click)="login()">Log in</button>
                                <p class="black2E circularBook mt-4 font-size12">Don't have an account?
                                    <a href="" class="circularMedium">Sign up</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

TS

```
  openModal() {
    $('#signInModal').modal('show');
  }
```

Code from other component

```
modalRef: BsModalRef;
 constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService
  ) { }

   join(){
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(SigninComponent);
   }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you using jQuery here..? That should not be needed..

Comment: @MikeOne it's JS, it is provided such a way in bootstrap 4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: Try to prevent using jQuery in an Angular app. Try using ngx-bootstrap for the functional stuff. You second example is how it should be done.

Comment: @MikeOne yeah I tried with the second example it is opening the modal window but I can see no modal content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your second attempt to show the dialog, it is evident that you are using `ngx-bootstrap`

As stated by @MikeOne **Do not use JQuery in an angular app** Angular is enough to bind your view to the model

### The Problem

I have tried to reproduce your code and discovered that for some reason, wrapping your content inside the below code is what seems to be making your code not to show the dialogue

```html
<section>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal()">Sign In</button>
    
    <div id="signInModal" class="modal fade m-5" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="dialog-sizes-name2" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">

          <!-- Other Stuff here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

### Solution

In your **LoginComponent** Simply have below

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="circularBold signUpHeading">Sign In</h6>
        <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            aria-label="Close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form [formGroup]="signInForm">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <button
                type="button"
                class="btn buttons nextBtn circularBold w-100"
                (click)="login()"
              >
                Log in
              </button>
                <p class="black2E circularBook mt-4 font-size12">
                    Don't have an account?
                    <a href="" class="circularMedium">Sign up</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See this solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-klrjtw)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `ngx-boostrap`

Add ngx-bootstrap as follows:

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component modals
```

It's mandatory to import `ModalModule` in `app.module.ts` as follows

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

for creating a simple template parent.component.ts file should be as follows

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { TemplateComponent } from './tempalte/template.component';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

 // Here the TemplateComponent includes the modal content. For that I  have created another component name "TemplateComponent" 

  openModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(TemplateComponent);
  }
}
```

In Template component template.component.ts file looks as follow

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-template',
    templateUrl: './template.component.html'
})
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public modalRef: BsModalRef) { }
ngOnInit(){}
}
```